# how can I pass parameter from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

the javascript code as below...how can I pass x to php?And there is not any button.

```
    function f(){
    var x = document.getElementById("point").innerHTML;
    }
```

And if I pass x to the php file,how can I receive it?

Comment: Google "AJAX", that's really all you need to get fast information.

Comment: ajax. Jquery example: `$.post('my.php', {x:x}, function(response){alert(response);});` php: `//my.php $x = $_POST['x']; echo 'value from js is: '.$x;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
function f(){
    var x = document.getElementById("point").innerHTML;
    window.location.href = 'page.php?point='+x;
}
```

And in page `page.php` try this,

```
$point = $_GET["point"];
```

Comment: Sorry,I have already tried it but the chrome echoed an error that "Uncaught ReferenceError: windows is not defined" to me.

Comment: @wind910037 : see my updated answer. change `windows` to `window`. It's my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The only to do so is by making an ajax request. For more info on making an ajax request, refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This out:**

```
function myFunction() {var javascriptVariable =document.getElementById("point").innerHTML;window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?name=" + javascriptVariable; }
```

On your myphpfile.php you can use $_GET['name'] after your javascript was executed.